# Keeping the excess whitespace in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i am trying to convert white space into `&nbsp;`

I have a tag in my html code `<pre></pre>` and contain blank space inside. I am originally trying to select the javascript value but maintaining the blank position. However i am awared that innerHTML does remove excess white space. Is there a way for me to keep the blank position. I am also trying to grab it before i do the innerHTML to do something of this sort

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {      
    var value = $("pre").val();
    value = value.replace(" ", "&nbsp");
    $("pre").val(value);

});
</script>
```

but it doesn't select the white space i guess.

Thank you for any help. I also don't have access to generate the html before it even gets display.

Comment: I don't understand your question, but you might want to try: `.replace(/\s/g, "&nbsp;");` in order to replace all occurrences of a space with `&nbsp;`

Comment: `val()` has nothing to do with the HTML, it sets and gets an elements value ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`val` method only works for form elements, for other elements you should `html`/`text` method instead.

```
$("pre").html(function(_, innerHTML) {
   return innerHTML.replace(/\s/g, "&nbsp;");
});
```

Comment: `/\s/g` will match newline characters which are usually significant in `<pre>` elements.